# Use a python projects requirements.txt as input to a Guix package definition?

Tags: guix

I have an existing Python project made by a friend that contains a `requirements.txt` that `pip install -r` normally consumes. A project that is not published to PyPI. Say that I wanted to use Guix as the package manager to provide the development environment/shell/virtualenv providing both Python itself and python modules, but would not like to keep a separate list of the needed packages and versions. Is it possible to use the `requirements.txt` as an input to a Guix package definition?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately this is not currently supported. Guix package names that aren't guaranteed to map to those used on PyPI and any one version of Guix typically only provides one or two versions of each package. The requirements.txt format also has a range of options such as installing from arbitrary Git repositories which won't correspond to a package in Guix.

This is something that *could* potentially be done in the future, for a subset of the requirements.txt features.

If you'd like to stick with Guix, you could create a `guix-requirements.scm` that duplicates your requirements.txt. Something like this perhaps:

```
(use-modules (guix)
             (gnu packages python)
             (gnu packages python-web))
(package
  (name "my-project-env")
  (propagated-inputs `(("python" ,python)
                       ("python-flask" ,python-flask))))
```

Run with `guix environment -l guix-requirements.scm`.

See [Invoking guix environment](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/guix.html#Invoking-guix-environment) for more.